# spring security: 404 error after successfull login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using spring security in spring boot. and here is my authorization configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password,enable from user where username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT username,sys_role "
                                        + " FROM user join user_sys_role on user.id=user_sys_role.user_id"
                                        + " where username=?");

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers( "/registeration").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/").hasRole("USER")
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .and().logout().permitAll();
        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
        http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/", true);
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }


}
```

It simply says, after the successful log in navigate to the page: `"/"`:

```
http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/", true);
```

But, it gives me a 404 error. I am sure i have the proper html page and the controller in the `/`

I doubled check my console, and the real error was:

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

---

Update:

the user class is:

```
 @Data
    @Entity
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class User {

       @ElementCollection 
       @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
       Collection<SystemRole> sysRole=EnumSet.of(SystemRole.USER);
```

and then the

```
public enum SystemRole {
    ADMIN,ORGANIZER,USER
}
```

Comment: In DB it should be `ROLE_USER`.

Comment: If you like to keep your authorities in your DB without role prefixe `ROLE_`, your can add the prefix in your configuration. Is it what you want?